# The meaning of 'shadow' accounts

Tags: meaning

[image]

I'm not an English native speaker. I need your help.

Could you explain to me the meaning of 'shadow' accounts? Is it secret bank accounts?

It doesn't need to be exact. I'm just studying. Thank you.

Comment: You provide no background for this and expect a response.

Comment: Also, this would probably be more on-topic at [ell.se].

Answer (score 2):

The use of inverted commas (aka *quotation marks* or *quotes*) around **“shadow”** strongly hints that this term is a euphemism, or a term which insiders /employees use among themselves. Technically, this type of drawing the reader's attention is called [*scared quotes*](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/quotes/scare).

> **[shadow accounting](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/shadow-accounting.html)**
>   Accounting system in which two separate sets of financial books are kept for the purpose of finding a mistake.
>   <sub>Business Dictionary</sub>

Wikipedia's page on **shadow system** suggests that a *shadow account* is secretive, hence the author's choice of inverted commas. It's his way of distancing himself from the meaning of the term.

> **[Shadow System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_system)** **is a term used in information services for any application relied upon for business processes that is not under the jurisdiction of a centralized information systems department**. That is, the information systems department did not create it, was not aware of it, and does not support it.

Comment: A related and common concept  is that of ***Shadow Banking***: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_banking_system

Answer (score 0):

Since "shadow account" is jargon, your question is really one of simple reading comprehension, and doesn't require any special insight into the English language. You should be able to get at least a general idea of what it means from the context of the passage -- in this case, something to do with creating either hidden, temporary, or false accounts, relative to what the software in this patent application actually does.  I expect the exact meaning is defined elsewhere in the document, since it seems to be a key part of the functionality.

Of course, not being a native speaker it might be difficult to know when a term is jargon limited to a particular field (or document), and when a term is idiom.  Usually, you can look up idioms in any dictionary.  If your term doesn't show up, poke around in the rest of the document and you'll probably find it.